# Java Factorization Failure - Why is it looping?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the code to find the factors for the user's input, give the prime factorization for the user's input, and give the lcm and gcm.  It is supposed to be simple.  It is an Intro to Programming class, but it is moving waaaaay too fast for me.  I've spent hours reading and studying and trying to get this code to work.  Please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PattersonFactorization {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //create scanner to obtain input from command window
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //initialization phase
        int input1 = 0; //initialize first input from user
        int input2 = 0; //initialize second input from user


        //prompt twice for two inputs from user 
        //until they enter a positive value for each input

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please provide your first positive number: ");
            input1 = input.nextInt();
        }//end do for input1
        while(input1 <= 0);

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please provide your next positive number: ");
            input2 = input.nextInt();
        }//end do for input2
        while(input2 <= 0);

        // call methods for factorization calculations
        calculateFactors(input1);
        calculateFactors(input2);
        calculatePrime(input1);
        calculatePrime(input2);
        calculateLCM(input1, input2);
        calculateGCF(input1, input2);


    }//end of main

    public static void calculateFactors(int input)
    {

        for(int countFactor = 1; countFactor < input; countFactor++)
        {
            if(countFactor % input == 0); 
            System.out.println(countFactor);
        }

    }//end of calculateFactors

    public static void calculatePrime(int input)
    {
        for(int countPrime = 1; countPrime < input; countPrime++)
        {
            if(countPrime % input == 0);
            System.out.println(countPrime);
            input = input/countPrime;
            countPrime--;
        }
    }//end of calculatePrime

    public static void calculateLCM(int input1, int input2)
    {
        for(int factorNum = 1; input1 % factorNum != 0 && input2 % factorNum != 0; factorNum++)
        System.out.println(factorNum);
    }//end of calculateLCM

    public static void calculateGCF(int input1, int input2)
    {
        for(int factorNum = input1; input1 % factorNum != 0 && input2 % factorNum != 0; factorNum--)
        System.out.println(factorNum);
    }

}//end of class
```

`

Comment: yes, "call methods for factorization calculations" is a comment.  I fixed it and tried to run it again.  It is just looping "1" endlessly when i run the program.

Comment: I got a 100% on my pseudocode design for the program and i followed it to the letter, but this is not working at all.

Comment: Just a note (though this won't solve your problem): you should close the scanner when you're done with it (e.g. put `input.close();` at the end of your `main` method).

Comment: You have several `if` statements that are followed by a ';' which means the following line won't be executed conditionally. For example, `if(countPrime % input == 0);` <- remove that `;`

Comment: thank you Neuronaut :)  Will do

Comment: @neuronaut - I disagree about closing the scanner opened for `Sytem.in` stream. It does not improve anything and in some circumstances can lead to a trouble.

Comment: @PM77-1 Good point, since Scanner tries to close the underlying input stream as well (which you wouldn't want to do on `System.in`). I was more trying to make a point that it's nearly always a good idea to close resources that you've opened -- not doing so is generally much more likely to end up causing problems in larger applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
        for(int countPrime = 1; countPrime < input; countPrime++)
        {
            if(countPrime % input == 0);
            System.out.println(countPrime);
            input = input/countPrime;
            countPrime--;
        }
```

You **decrement** `countPrime` in the loop that **increments** it.  As the result it never changes its value.

Comment: Thank you.  It stopped looping 1!  ~hugs~  I appreciate you :)

Comment: You are welcome. Please continue studying.  Programming can be a lot of fun.

Comment: I love VBA and SQL, but this Java stuff is totally its own animal.  I don't even understand the lingo yet, let alone the applications of these intricate interwoven concepts and cryptic syntax.  I feel like I'm looking in the window of a clubhouse full of peeps chattering in Alienese...I just want to turn tail and bolt!  But i gotta get through this semester first...eeks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

```
if(countFactor % input == 0);
System.out.println(countFactor);
```

Your code here will always execute `System.out.println(countFactor);` regardless of the value of your conditional expression. The problem is `if(countFactor % input == 0);` - your `if` has a semicolon at the end.

You could either use [no braces in this case](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

```
if(countFactor % input == 0)
    System.out.println(countFactor);
```

But it is nearly always more clear to use **braces** to both clearly to the coder and the compiler show the scope:

```
if(countFactor % input == 0) {
    System.out.println(countFactor);
}
```

Your infinite loop is coming from both incrementing and decrementing `countPrime` in your `for` loop:

```
for(int countPrime = 1; countPrime < input; countPrime++)
{
    if(countPrime % input == 0);
    System.out.println(countPrime);
    input = input/countPrime;
    countPrime--;
}
```

`countPrime` will be decremented to `0` at the end of your loop and then incremented back to `1` on the next loop iteration. `input = input/countPrime;` will always be `input = input/1`, which is another reason why your termination expression is never `true`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help mkobit.